# Windows Service output

Tags: windows

What happens to messages printed to stdout and stderr from a Windows service? I know they're not going anywhere, but do they go down /dev/null? Is it possible that an application will block during such a write ?

Comment: Question is off-topic, you should know this. Post it in Super Users

Comment: Do you have a Windows service you've written that's hanging where you suspect this might be the case? @Chelseawillrecover: This is about a service writing to `stdout` or `stderr`, which are programming terms. Users don't refer to them that way, so it's clearly a (somewhat) programming-related question.

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover is more on topic here, this is a question from the development point of view.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The output will effectively go to dev/null, and won't introduce a blocking issue. Now performance on the other-hand *will* be impacted, as it does take resources to write it out.

Ideally, you would be able to configure where logs end up. A nicely implemented service will allow for:

- Writting logs to one or more of: a file, debug output, console output (when running local instances for testing/debugging), potentially even a database.
- Ability to specify the path to where log files are written.
- Configure how long logs are kept around (the service should be able to purge older logs to prevent HDD leaks)
- Specify how frequently to start a new file (so you don't end up with 18 gigabyte log files).
- Ideally, you also want the ability to configure how much data to log (what level of detail).

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that the output will always be harmlessly discarded.  Best practice is to make sure you don't use standard output from a service or from a GUI application.

Comment: Btw, stdout on GUI applications work just fine. It's really nice to log to stdout as programs can read that (if started with piping and so on), but it doesn't bother the user.