# Call console methods in service-based app

Tags: c#, .net, service, console-application

In my application i have class `MainManager`, that can be run as windows service and as console app (for dev and debug purpose). In code i have plenty `Console.WriteLine(...)` and  `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White` etc. that output some data when i use it as console application.

Is it good if i run same code as service? There is no console where output goes, but code still valid. How that affect performance? Will i have possible issues with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523480/windows-service-output

Comment: @RenniePet yes, thanks alot. Your search ability is supreme, good job.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into a framework like [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to handle this for you.

If it is strictly performance you are concerned about, any code that executes takes time, you could wrap your output statements in compiler directives:

```
#if (AsConsoleApp)
Console.WriteLine("Log message here.");
#endif
```

You can use the [/define](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) compiler option to turn your statements on or off.

Comment: Well, thanks, i will try it for sure. But i want to know answers on my question anyway.